# iOS or Responsive Web Photo App with Large Captions/Descriptions for Presentations

Tags: web-apps, ios, photography

A colleague of mine was looking for an easier solution for showing progress on projects.

Currently, photographs of the progress are taken daily and text describing the work some place everyone working on the project can save and get to them. My colleague then uses the images and text in a PowerPoint to use in regular meetings with the client. They are arranged in a grid layout with the photo to the left and the text describing it (date, work down, etc.) to the right.

**The problems with this set up:**

- Images and text are de-coupled
- If images have to be added/removed, the grid may need to change (2x2 to 3x3), which is slow
- It is difficult/not practical to adjust the view during the meeting if the client wants a closer look

**Desired Solution**

An iOS or web app where:

- The people taking the photos can add a text description that stays with the photo
- There is a grid/gallery view of the images *along with the text at a readable size*
- The app automatically dates the photo, which is included in the photo's caption/description
- The user can select what grid size they want OR
- The user can select how large the image & text view is and the grid size adjusts automatically
- The user can select which images are in the gallery/grid view

  - Preferred: The user can select a date range for the gallery/grid view
- Preferred: Ability to hide these uploads from the public/share photos with a group

**Problem with Typical Photo Apps**

Most photo apps assume that any caption is unimportant. The text is extremely small, below the image instead of next to it, often can't be formatted, and often disappears entirely in any grid view of the photos. They're set up for having really nice views of photography, not viewing images with relevant, descriptive text.

**Restrictions**

They were looking for something that was free: both no-cost and no ads. I couldn't find one so for the purposes of asking here, I'm just looking for something with no ads. The lower the cost the better but ad-free is required, even if it means paying for a pro-version.

The question came up months ago; this is me asking after the fact.